# Problem in viewing recent posts from network site to main site

Tags: multisite

I have created a website in wordpress **damiracle.com** where there I already made a Blog Page. But the client wants to host the blog in a subdomain **blog.damiracle.com** and with different theme. So I made **damiracle.com**, the main and the network admin site after following all the procedure of Codex Creating a Network.

After creating the Network I added a new site for blog which is in a sub domain named as **blog.damiracle.com**.

I also installed WordPress MU Domain Mapping and WordPress MU Sitewide Tags Pages to view the Recent posts from the **blog.damiracle.com** to the **damiracle.com** but I am facing problem in viewing the posts from the **blog.damiracle.com** to **damiracle.com**. All the posts are viewing are the recent posts which are already inside the blog page of **damiracle.com**

I know that I am going wrong but I can't figure out what wrong actually I am doing.

Comment: That plugin is listed as compatible us to 3.3.2 but WordPress is now at 3.8. The plugin may simply not work any longer. Sorry, but as written this question seems to be "Can you debug and fix this plugin I'm using". That is "work for me for free" in my mind.

Comment: Have a look at [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) and [`restore_current_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog).

Comment: Thanks PatJ hope your solution may work. I will use this and let you know